# Django prompt ：A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator

Tags: python, django

I have tried everything I can find, and it has been 6 hours.
I have nothing, I just created a django project, and the first time I run, I get an error.
I've tried both, reinstall django, python 'encoding format, file encoding format.
I am frustrated, please help me.

Rework the question：

I just created a project that is accessible to the page. But when I create an application and create a view page, the django homepage is error：

“A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.”

But the new view is accessible.

The error displayed is as follows:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", lin
e 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 133, in
__call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 75, in g
et_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36,
 in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90,
 in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), s
ys.exc_info())
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125
, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technica
l_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_tra
ceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
  File "C:\python\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 233836: inv
alid start byte
[25/Feb/2020 21:52:34] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Comment: Don't post errors as images; that just makes it harder for us to help.  Post the entire error as plain text.

Comment: sorry， i have changed to text